# ASP.NET MVC 5 bootstrap button move to another view page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I want to move to another page from current

**My View**

```
<p class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">@Html.ActionLink("More information", "GoToApps") More information! &raquo;</p>
```

However my button have link from method ActionLink and string "More information". How is method without linkText ?

**My method in controller:**

```
public ActionResult GoToApps()
    {
        return RedirectToAction("IndexApps", "Apps");
    }
```

This way is run, but I want better display.
Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

If you need only Link you should use `@Url.Action("GoToApps")`

Comment: I tried earlier there example. And this code dispaly in my bootstrap button "Home/GoToApps" When I click not move to IndexApps.

Answer (score -1):

```
<form action="@Html.ActionLink("More information", "GoToApps")">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"> More information! &raquo;</button>
</form>
```